# Filtering lotus-domino views that have multiple categories and multiple values

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to design a view with multiple categories, and each document can belong to multiple categories at the same time. 
For example, File A is in category:
1->a;
2

I can achieve this effect by specifying the columns as categories and access the document through various routes. However, I fail to specify which category the sub-categories belong to. This is what I am getting instead:
1->a;
2->a

The case doesn't seem too big of a difference but basically the view is returning every combination of the categories and the amount of entries can get very large.

I have tried to add the super category in front of the sub-category and try to filter out entries which the categories do not match the prefix of the sub-categories(e.g. 1,a), but I cannot find a way filter them out. Although the multiple values are shown in different entries, when I try to use the variable it extracts all the values.

Is there a way I can filter the entries based on that particular row instead of all the values? Or is there anyway I can achieve the effect through other methods? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use ViewNavigator only. That's the only way to work with entries inside multiple categories.

Answer (score 2):

You need to collapse Categories and subcategories into a single field. The Domino way to do this is to separate category and subcategory by backslash. So your category field would be something like:

```
 "1\a":"2"
```

That ties the subcategory to the category. Or if you want to be able to find a document by subcategory only:

```
 "1\a":"a":"2"
```

You then can use a little formula magic to get from the subcategory back to the main category (presuming the subcategories don't duplicate):

```
 AllCategories := "1\a":"a":"2";
 foundCategory := "a";   
 @Trim(@Replace(AllCategories;foundCategory:@Trim(@ReplaceSubstring(allCategories;foundCategory)));
```

This would return `"1\a"` (Note: the formula above is written is classic @Formula language, it is left as an exercise to the reader to translate that to the JavaScript formula equivalent)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand the formula language, but I couldn't figure out how to populate the whole table using the formula. However, I found out that using backslash to categorize items does not yield every combination of the entries. I only need to use spaces to fill up the fields. I thought I solved my problem

Comment: I thought I solved my problem just now, but I can't indent the subcategories in my xpage view Panel. I might have to try a little bit more. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Elaborate more on "yield every combination". What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. Let's say I have an object belonging to category "1";"2"and"3" and has the subCategory "a";"b","c"; The subcategory a,b,c belongs to 123 respectively, so the object is in "1\a";"2\b";"3\c". but categorizing both columns will give all 3X3 combinations:1*abc 2*abc and 3*abc. I have added the category name before the subCategory to eliminate unwanted copies. i.e. (1\1-a), and I want to select out the entries that do not match(2\1-a) but fail to do so.

Comment: You need to have one field with categories. You can't do that with 2 columns. The column approach gives you permutations. Your field should be something like 1:1\a:2:2\b:3:3\b then when you categorize that one column you get exactly what you need.

Comment: I get the results I want with one column but I cannot get the indentation in my xpage view control. Maybe I will stick to the traditional view. Thanks a lot.